# Php write to log also when @ is used to suppress a warning

Tags: php, logging, web, warnings

In PHP sometimes we prepend a function call with the @ operator to suppress the warnings that can be eventually shown on the page. 
Assuming that the application is set up to log error and warnings to a file, when a warning is "suppressed" its correspondent entry in the logfile will be created anyway?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? `@` should never be used anyways. There's almost never a valid usage case.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding, that it won't write to the log file - after reading http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

It effectively temporarilly sets the error reporting level to 0, and I believe if the error reporting level is 0, errors are not written to the log